# program ignoring if statement, and printing True when False

Tags: python, if-statement, statements

I am writing a simple program for a homework problem and It seems to be skipping my if statement. I have looked at other questions posed, and the problems there do not seem to be my problem so I am hoping you can help.

```
def isWordGuessed(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
if lettersGuessed == []:
    return False
else:
    for i in lettersGuessed:
        if i in secretWord == False:
            return False

        else:
            if i == lettersGuessed[-1]:
                return True
```

When I place in some print functions to see what it is doing, it completely skips

```
if i in secretWord == False:
```

I have placed right above this line

```
print i in secretWord
```

and it will print out the correct Boolean, but even when it prints False, it still skips the if statement. I feel like I must be overlooking something pretty basic, but what it is I can't seem to figure out, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Edit:

Here is an example of a call to this function with inputs

```
isWordGuessed('apple',['a','e','i','k','p','r','s'])
```

Comment: Can you post your input parameters?

Comment: I edited the original post to include input info

Comment: As a general rule, comparing things to `True` or `False` is a bad idea. Comparing to `True` should usually be dropped, and comparing to `False` should usually be replaced with a `not`.

Comment: @user2357112: This is one of the most basic and common mistake beginners make and at face value, because it seems logical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
        if i in secretWord == False:
```

This doesn't do what you think it does. If you want this path to be taken when `i` isn't in `secretWord`, you want

```
        if i not in secretWord:
```

What you have does a [chained comparison](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in). First, it checks

```
i in secretWord
```

If that's true, it then checks

```
secretWord == False
```

If that's true (which it won't be), it then takes the `if` path.

Comment: Ah ok, I get it. So if I were to set 'i in secretWord' to a variable, and then check if that variable was true or false, it would work as well correct? (obviously the 'not in' is the better solution)

Answer (score 1):

Replace `if i in secretWord == False:` with `if i not in secretWord`

Comment: Thank you, this does make the program work, but I would still like to know why this method does not work, so that I can have a better understanding of it conceptually.

Comment: You are making a chained comparison. The other answer from user2347112 had posted a link to it. Please refer to that. I don't want to repeat the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I had actually posted this at the same time he posted his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldnt it be the same just doing:

``

```
def isWordGuessed(secretWord, lettersGuessed):

if not lettersGuessed:
    return False
for i in lettersGuessed:
    if i not in secretWord:
        return False
return True
```

What your doing is called chained comparisons.

Edit: My bad, too late

BR Daniel

Answer (score 0):

The other answers explain the error in the code well, but you can simplify your code a bit like this:

```
def isWordGuessed(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
    for i in lettersGuessed or ['_']: # uses ['_'] when lettersGuessed = []
        if not i in secretWord:
            return False
    return True
```

You can do also do this with a generator expression and `all()`:

```
def isWordGuessed(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
    return all([i in secretWord for i in lettersGuessed] or [False])
```